# Confirmation box didnt show hebrew

Tags: javascript, asp.net, confirmation

I build my project in asp.net and for one of my frm I write script with confermation box.

The function works great beside the hebrew msg. ie and chrom showen "?" mark instead of the hebrew characters i wrote.

```
function ConfirmDeleteTeacher() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm("בלה בלה?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

Comment: which language is this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an encoding issue. Try saving your document with a different encoding, I would suggest UTF-8.

To do this in Visual Studio: Open the document, go to File -> Save as and in the dialog that opens, the Save button has an arrow with options. Choose "Save with encoding" and then choose the appropriate encoding.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I sloved the problem by adding the configuration this definition

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="windows-1255"
    responseEncoding="windows-1255" />
</system.web>
```

now the hebrew is working :)