# Cannot search Mysql for greek strings

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I cant get any result set back, when issuing a simple Select statement through VB.Net and MySql Data provider, to a Mysql table searching for some Greek string.
MYSQL Ver:5.5.32
VB.Net: 2010

Do I need any special encoding for the passed string?

PS: Have already tried the solutions posted bellow:

1. What encoding is the β character in? Where does the input come from? If it's from your console, you need to make sure it uses UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1 –  Pekka 웃 Aug 11 '11 at 8:05
2. Try to use: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); –  reven Oct 26 '11 at 12:36

My code looks like the fllowing:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim utf8Encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

    Dim sql, st As String
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim com As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SET NAMES 'utf8'", MysqlConn)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    bytes = (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text))
    st = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
    sql = "Select * from Customers where name like '%" & st & "%'".ToString

    Dim command As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)

    da.SelectCommand = command

    da.Fill(ds)
    MysqlConn.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

In my experience from VB.NET in ASP.NET, there are a few things that need to be done so that Greek (e.g. non-latin) characters to work:

**Database**: The collation of the database should be set to UTF-8.

**Connection string**: Make sure that your connection string has the 'Character Set' set to UTF-8.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connstr" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Database=db_name;User ID=db_user;Password=db_pass;Character Set=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Code files**: All code files must be saved with the UTF-8 (with signature) encoding. This is the default for all Visual Studio files. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315215/confermation-box-didnt-show-hebrew/) the steps to check if they are saved as UTF-8.

I am guessing that you have a WinForms application, so most likely your vb files are saved correctly, and thus, your input is UTF-8 and you don't need to convert it.

If your database doesn't have its collation set to UTF-8 only then you need to convert your input from UTF-8 to the encoding your db has.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with using MySql. However, going through UTF-8 may be the problem (.NET uses UTF-16 for strings). You could try it like this:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable

Dim sql, st As String
sql = "Select * from Customers where name like ?name"

Dim command As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
Dim theName As String = "%" & TextBox2.Text & "%"
da.Parameters.Add("name", theName)
da.SelectCommand = command

da.Fill(ds)
MysqlConn.Close()

DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Please adjust the line `da.Parameters.Add("name", theName)` if necessary - e.g. it might require the data type and size.